# Why windows 7 search becomes too slow after frequently use?

Tags: windows-7, search, file-management, file-search

**Situation:** We are working on a file management project where we need to generate and sort around 60,000 files per day and burn them in DVD's everyday as the final output. All files have JPG extension with the size between 100 KB to 400 KB. They are stored on a 16 TB storage server on a LAN network in folders of 300 each, but when we want to burn them in a DVD, they should not be in folders, a DVD should contain only and only JPG files. So to achieve that, and also get rid of thumbs.db (that are created by PC's over network accessing files), first the folders are copied to PC's the desktop and then we use `*.JPG` search and get only pure JPG files to burn to DVD. DVD-burning process is to be done by one person from one PC only, that runs windows 7 professional. We also use windows server 2008.

**Problem:** During the process of DVD-burning, *initially the search is fast as expected (around 5 seconds for a DVD)* and we see a green progress bar quickly flashing the address bar, but *after burning three to four DVD's, search becomes too slow, and one DVD could take up to three hours* (and the green progress bar is not displayed any longer)!

**Question:** What is it possibly because of? And how to prevent that low speed search?

Comment: Couldn't you script this somehow?

Comment: Its slow because your looking at a network location.  Windows will cache the previous result but only to a certain part highly dependent on the system itself doing the searching.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I forgot to mention that before searching he copies the files to the desktop, and then searches them, I modified the question also.

Comment: @Zoredache We have developed a system for this in JAVA, but this part has so much customization, that is why we keep it manual.